# Python: Separating string into individual letters/words to be converted into ascii-hex or ascii-dec

Tags: python, string, ascii

As the title suggests, I want to get a string, split it into individual bits to input into something like ord('') and get a value for each individual character in that string. Still learning python so things like this get super confusing :P. Furthermore, the process for encryption for each of the codes will just be to shift the alphabet's dec number by a specified value and decrypt into the shifted value, plus state that value for each character. How would i go about doing this? any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

```
message=input("Enter message here: ", )
shift=int(input("Enter Shift....explained shift: ", )
for c in list(message):
    a=ord(c)
    print c
```

This is the very basic idea of what i was doing (was more code but similar), but obviously it didn't work :C, the indented--> just means that it was indented, just don't know how to do that in stack overflow. 
UPDATE: IT WORKS (kinda) using the loop and tweaking it according to the comments i got a list of every single ascii dec value for each character in the string!, ill try and use @Hugh Bothwell's suggestion within the loop and hopefully get some work done.

Comment: `list(inputstring)`. Or just loop: `for character in inputstring:`. Strings are sequences already, after all.

Comment: Could you post an example of the initial string ?

Comment: Either post code you've already tried and didn't work, or I'm going to assume you want us to do your hw assigment for you.

Comment: Sorry, ill get to doing that, i'm using a SSH shell to access the server so atm I cant copy paste the code, but given some time I definitely will. Sorry for making it seem like i was asking for you guys to do my work for me, stuck in a jam :(

Comment: also for tk, something basic like "i like cookies", the main purpose for me undertaking this is to find a way to convert to and from ascii  as I am learning python on my own and need to learn a lot still.

Comment: edited if you guys want :P

Answer (score 1):

```
mystring = "this is a test"
shift = 3
encoded = ''.join(chr(ord(ch) + shift) for ch in mystring)
```

You'll have to do a little more if you want your alphabet to wrap around, ie encode('y') == 'b', but this should give you the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks!, tried it and it works, but for the purposes of this, i ended up using just chr(whatevercharacter +shift), anyways thanks!